# Place & retrieve some files (e.g. images) in my android app

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android and I have a folder of images and need to load and show them in my app using Gridview(something like android gallery). for this task I used [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) library.

Now my question is where is the best place to put this folder of images in application package(i.e in res or assets folder or etc) and how can I get its path in runtime?

P.S. I know about Drawable directory but I need sth other than this, e.g. I want to put my images in res/raw but how can I get raw directory path in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The best way to store a folder of images, make a sub-folder under Assets folder then you can get its file names in run-time using the following command:

```
getAssets().list("sub-folder")
```

and get the stream of each file using:

```
getAssets().open("sub-folder/file-name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place your all images in `res/drawable` folder
Now if you to use image, say you want to set it on the image view, Simply write:

```
<imageView
android:width="wrap_content"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/image_name"/>
```

or programmatically:

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

> A bitmap file is a .png, .jpg, or .gif file. Android creates a Drawable resource for any of these files when you save them in the res/drawable/ directory.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

In the code you can get them using *R.drawable.file_name*

Comment: I know about Drawable directory but I need sth other than this, I want to put a folder of images in res, and get its absolute path in runtime